# How to preserve all elements in geojson linestring while importing as geopandas dataframe (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, geopandas

I am trying to import a GeoJSON file as a geopandas dataframe:

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'vehicle': 63},
 'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
  'coordinates': [[-121.579609, 39.777788, 14.21, 1609520401.0],
   [-121.581177, 39.777786, 14.04, 1609520411.0],
   [-121.58277, 39.777762, 13.64, 1609520421.0],
   [-121.584358, 39.777759, 13.91, 1609520431.0],...
{'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'vehicle': 283},
   'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': [[-121.600506, 39.777636, 12.58, 1609520403.0],
     [-121.599111, 39.777643, 11.71, 1609520413.0],
     [-121.597714, 39.777671, 12.29, 1609520423.0],
     [-121.596323, 39.77769, 12.03, 1609520433.0],...
```

After I import with:

```
gpdf = gpd.read_file('file.geojson',
                    driver='GeoJSON')
```

The last (4th) element in each `coordinates` list (e.g.1609520401.0) is missing:

```
    vehicle geometry
0   63      LINESTRING Z (-121.57961 39.77779 14.21000, -1...
1   283     LINESTRING Z (-121.60051 39.77764 12.58000, -1...
2   519     LINESTRING Z (-121.63427 39.77045 14.03000, -1...
3   2253    LINESTRING Z (-121.60616 39.77775 16.94000, -1...
4   2376    LINESTRING Z (-121.58091 39.80047 13.01000, -1...
```

Note that the linestring now ends in the 3rd element from each list (e.g. 14.21000).

I confirmed the problem by exporting as a GeoJSON file.

Does anyone see what I did wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

According to `geoJSON` specifications: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-7.

3.1.1 Position

> A position is an array of numbers.  There MUST be two or more
> elements.  The first two elements are longitude and latitude, or
> easting and northing, precisely in that order and using decimal
> numbers.  Altitude or elevation MAY be included as an optional third
> element.
>
> Implementations SHOULD NOT extend positions beyond three elements
> because the semantics of extra elements are unspecified and
> ambiguous.  Historically, some implementations have used a fourth
> element to carry a linear referencing measure (sometimes denoted as
> "M") or a numerical timestamp, but in most situations a parser will
> not be able to properly interpret these values.  The interpretation
> and meaning of additional elements is beyond the scope of this
> specification, and additional elements MAY be ignored by parsers.

You did nothing wrong. The `parser` just ignored the 4th `elements` of the coordinates in the geojson content.

Comment: Thank you @swatchai! Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @Dlinnard The geojson file can be edited to contain additional `properties` items of the data of your choice. In your case you can extract the 4th elements and created them as a new feature property called `list_of_timestamps`.